# tutorial for philsturgeon codeigniter-oauth2 library

Tags: codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk, twitter-oauth

I want to make a "sign in with twitter /facebook" web apps with codeigniter . It seems everybody suggest me to use https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-oauth2 library.

Is there any complete tutorial using that library ? or any alternative library with complete tutorial to use it?

Comment: This is very old & no longer maintained (wasn't updated in a year) + it doesn't contain Twitter in the providers list And the Facebook permissions list is no longer valid due to Facebook updates. (I don't expect this to work at all without modifications).

Comment: @ahmad so do you have any alternative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A3M sounds like something you could use. It has normal user authentication, facebook, twitter, google, yahoo and openid.

Give it a try to see if it has what you need.

https://github.com/donjakobo/A3M

Comment: sorry but the link is broken , 404 not found

Comment: Strange, works completely fine for me. If it still doesn't work you can search for A3M on GitHub or give it another try via my test site: a3m.freedombase.net